# Detect File Download on Browser by Proxy Server [python]

Tags: python, http, browser, download, proxy

I have proxy server in python that forwards and intercepts all the responses and requests.

For security issues, I need to analyzing every file that the client asks to download. Unfortunately, I don't know when the response (the client get from the webserver) have file that should download or it's an element that should be displayed on the webpage.

Do you have any idea how I filter just the file that should download?

**EDIT:** I tried to filter that by the header `Content-Disposition` but not all the MIME-Types that should be downloaded has that header in the response packet.

Comment: Didn't get after "Unfortunately.."

Comment: I run special analysis on file that the client downloads. Now I don't know to filter the response that contains the file the client asks for download.
For example-  the client can ask for pdf file , and it should be displayed in the browser in some cases and in other cases it should be downloaded.

Comment: If you are serving HTML5 then add `<a....download>` to make sure that the file is not opened by the browser, but downloaded. You can let the user know in advance that certain extensions `.pdf` are to be downloaded when requested.

Comment: I'm sorry if I was not clear in the first time, What I actually mean is that I want to know when the client asks for file download (when the popup on the browser shows up). My main problem is that there's a lot of MIME Types that should be displayed rather than download to the client disk. I want to filter the one's who download to the client machine.
I try to filter this by the header `Content-Disposition` but not all the files that download contains that header in the response (the responses that contains the file)

Comment: `Content-disposition` headers are useful for clients for determining the filename. I can tell what I know. If you serve `<a href="file.pdf" download>` the client is bound to download it. If `<a href="file.pdf>"`, you have no control over what happens. It will depend on the client config. If something is intercepting download, it will be downloaded. If not, it will not be.

Comment: I cannot serve by that because I'm just the proxy server, not the webserver that deliver the data. I cannot change those things because it may harm the webpage display or something else...
I just need to know when the client gets file for download so I can analyze it in my server ,I need something like a pattern or something that I can filter the response that contains file for download.